# Issue with form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I've tried placing this form inside of jsfiddle to find out that it does not function properly. The form does not validate any fields if input is incorrect and it does not continue on to the second portion of the form.

Here is how it's supposed to function (scroll to bottom): http://infinite-woodland-5276.herokuapp.com/forms-validation.html

Here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j31qm806/3/

```
  init.push(function() {
    $('#wizard-forms').pixelWizard({
      onFinish: function() {
        // Disable changing step. To enable changing step just call this.unfreeze()
        this.freeze();
      }
    });
    $('#wizard-forms .wizard-prev-step-btn').on('click', function() {
      $('#wizard-forms').pixelWizard('prevStep');
      return false;
    });

    // Account page

    $("#wizard-account").validate({
      ignore: '.ignore',
      focusInvalid: true,
      rules: {
        'username': {
          required: true,
          minlength: 3,
          maxlength: 20
        },
        'password': {
          required: true,
          minlength: 6,
          maxlength: 20
        },
        'repeat-password': {
          required: true,
          minlength: 6,
          equalTo: 'input[name="password"]'
        },
        'email': {
          required: true,
          email: true
        },
      }
    });
    $('#wizard-account').on('submit', function() {
      if ($(this).valid()) {
        $('#wizard-forms').pixelWizard('nextStep');
      }
      return false;
    });

    // Profile page

    $('#country').select2({
      allowClear: true,
      placeholder: 'Select a country...'
    }).change(function() {
      $(this).valid();
    });
    $("#wizard-profile").validate({
      ignore: '.ignore, .select2-input',
      focusInvalid: true,
      rules: {
        'full_name': {
          required: true
        },
        'country': {
          required: true
        },
        'subscription': {
          required: true
        },
        'gender1': {
          require_from_group: [1, 'input[name="gender1"], input[name="gender2"]']
        },
        'gender2': {
          require_from_group: [1, 'input[name="gender1"], input[name="gender2"]']
        }
      }
    });
    $('#wizard-profile').on('submit', function() {
      if ($(this).valid()) {
        $('#wizard-forms').pixelWizard('nextStep');
      }
      return false;
    });

    // Credit card page

    var $wcc = $('#wizard-credit-card')
    $wcc.find('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    $wcc.find('input[name="postal_code"]').mask("999999");
    $wcc.find('input[name="credit_card_number"]').mask("9999 9999 9999 9999");
    $wcc.find('input[name="csv"]').mask("999");
    $wcc.validate({
      ignore: '.ignore, .select2-input',
      focusInvalid: true,
      rules: {
        'postal_code': {
          required: true,
          digits: true,
          rangelength: [6, 6]
        },
        'credit_card_number': {
          required: true,
          creditcard: true
        },
        'csv': {
          required: true,
          digits: true,
          rangelength: [3, 3]
        }
      }
    });
    $wcc.on('submit', function() {
      if ($(this).valid()) {
        $('#wizard-forms').pixelWizard('nextStep');
      }
      return false;
    });

    // Finish page

    $('#wizard-finish button').click(function() {
      $(this).parent().find('.text-lg').text('THANK YOU!');
      $(this).parent().find('.fa-check').removeClass('fa-check').addClass('fa-check-circle');
      $(this).remove();
      $('#wizard-forms').pixelWizard('nextStep');
      return false;
    });

  });
```

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: ReferenceError: init is not defined
init.push(function() {}
remove this error first.

Comment: @Rohit no there is no error.